# Blazor change class without refreshing page

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

i have been working on a website but i want to change the class the sidebar but it only changes after a page refresh.

this is the main layout page

```
<div class="@(layoutState.IsOpen ? "sidebar" : "test")">
        <NavMenu />
</div>
```

and this is the navmenu page

```
<RadzenButton Click="() => layoutState.ChangeOpen()" class="btn btn-primary"><i
                    class=" @(layoutState.IsOpen ? "bi bi-arrow-left" : "bi bi-arrow-right")"></i></RadzenButton>
```

and this is the cs

```
public class LayoutState
    {
        public bool IsOpen { get; set; } = true;

        public void ChangeOpen(){
            IsOpen = !IsOpen;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have full context for what are you trying to achieve, but based on your present code

Once you change IsOpen in LayoutState, UI is not aware of it and the IsOpen changes stay within LayoutState, so you can use StateHasChanged() to ReRender UI to reflect latest changes

```
<button @onclick="() => {layoutState.ChangeOpen(); StateHasChanged();}" class="btn btn-primary"><i
                    class=" @(layoutState.IsOpen ? "bi bi-arrow-left" : "bi bi-arrow-right")"></i></button>
```